# Mapping dependent observable to sub list

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

Say I have the following two observable streams

```
IObservable<LibraryView> GetLibrariesSource();
IObservable<FolderView> GetLibraryFolderSource(LibraryView library);
```

so `IObservable<FolderView>` depends upon a `LibraryView`. Also these views are flat, i.e. they have no navigational properties.

How would I map these two streams to an `IObservable<Library>` stream, where `Library` has a list of `Folder`s

```
public class Library
{
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming that I can easily map from a `LibraryView` to a `Library` and from a `FolderView` to a `Folder`.

Also, My end goal is to simply get a `List<Library>` using e.g., `ForEachAsync`. So it may not be necessary to create an `IObservable<Library>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your problem space looks like this:

```
async Task Do()
{
    var libraryMapper = new Func<LibraryView, Library>(lv => /*implement me*/ new Library());
    var folderMapper = new Func<FolderView, Folder>(fv => /*implement me*/ new Folder());

    var librariesSource = new Func<IObservable<LibraryView>>(() => /*implement me*/ Observable.Empty<LibraryView>());
    var libraryFolderSource = new Func<LibraryView, IObservable<FolderView>>(lv => /*implement me*/ Observable.Empty<FolderView>());

}

public class Library 
{
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}
public class Folder { }
public class LibraryView { }
public class FolderView { }
```

Then something like this will work inside `Do()`:

```
var libraryList = await librariesSource()
    .Select(lv => (LibraryView: lv, FolderViewObservable: libraryFolderSource(lv)))
    .SelectMany(async t => (LibraryView: t.LibraryView, FolderViews: await t.Item2.ToList()))
    .Select(t =>
    {
        var newLibrary = libraryMapper(t.LibraryView);
        newLibrary.Folders = t.FolderViews.Select(fv => folderMapper(fv)).ToList();
        return newLibrary;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Use `Select` to map, `SelectMany` to apply `await` calls, and `await` to get from `IObservable<IList<T>>` to `IList<T>`.